# How to make a displacement like image on coin

Tags: displacement

I'm trying to find a way to make an image displace to work with a coin - kinda like Han Solo frozen in carbonite / regular coin style texture.  I've tried using various black and white (neg & positive) but ends up with the bumps coming out all janky.

Ideally I'd like to use a png / jpeg etc rather than sculpt it.

Something like this:
https://coinscatalog.net/images/big/15/sovereign-elizabeth-ii-2000-proof-uk-r-34554.jpg

Any help, gladly appreciated!!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: what is your image? Also, can you use a height or normal map instead of real 3D?

Comment: Hi @moonboots - basically I want a technique that will work with any image. A face / horse / mountain etc...  can use height / normal map, but ideally I'd like to be able to output a 3D file for printing.

Comment: It looks like a rather complicated task because you need a software that will guess what are the hollows and bumps, it needs a special lighting, etc. You can try to use a b&w image in a Displace modifier, it will interpret black as 0 thickness and white as thickness of 1, but it may give weird result.

Comment: sounds more like an AI task... ;)

Answer (score 1):

There's [this site](https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/) in which you can get the normal map of any photo from it.
Here's What the coin would look like:
[image]

It's not perfect, but it's fast and free.
Then you could use this normal map on your plane.